# Is there an implementation for module reflection/representation (similar to Generic for types, data)?

Tags: haskell, reflection, module, generic-programming

I've read about [generic programming](https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2014.2.0.0/ghc/users_guide/generic-programming.html) in Haskell with the use of `Generic` typeclass, as well as various older type-representations. (I've still haven't figured out the fine differences between the available stuff for this, the pros and cons. People did similar things before without `Generic`, and it's not clear yet for me what it gives now additionally. But that's not the topic of this question.)

Is it possible to "reflect" in a similar way the interface of a module, so that I can programmatically access the list of exported functions (and types), and convert from a representation with a name of the function to the function.

My idea for using this is the following:

- What is possible already: when the compiled program is run, it reads a formatted representation of data and evaluates a fixed function on it. (The format writer and reader are implemented by using the instances of a typeclass providing generic representations, like aeson or aeson-generic for formatting in JSON.)
- Now I want to add another bit: the name of the function to call is read, too. It determines the type of the data, and the used reader for the data. Reads the input data, and evaluates the function on this data.

To save manually writing the module interface in a function which does this interaction, I thought there might be some approaches to module reflection similar to generics.

---

An example of reflection for types, data from https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2014.2.0.0/ghc/users_guide/generic-programming.html:

```
instance Generic (UserTree a) where
  -- Representation type
  type Rep (UserTree a) =
    M1 D D1UserTree (
          M1 C C1_0UserTree (
                M1 S NoSelector (K1 R a)
            :*: M1 S NoSelector (K1 R (UserTree a))
            :*: M1 S NoSelector (K1 R (UserTree a)))
      :+: M1 C C1_1UserTree U1)

  -- Conversion functions
  from (Node x l r) = M1 (L1 (M1 (M1 (K1 x) :*: M1 (K1 l) :*: M1 (K1 r))))
  from Leaf         = M1 (R1 (M1 U1))
  to (M1 (L1 (M1 (M1 (K1 x) :*: M1 (K1 l) :*: M1 (K1 r))))) = Node x l r
  to (M1 (R1 (M1 U1)))                                      = Leaf

-- Meta-information
data D1UserTree
data C1_0UserTree
data C1_1UserTree

instance Datatype D1UserTree where
  datatypeName _ = "UserTree"
  moduleName _   = "Main"

instance Constructor C1_0UserTree where
  conName _ = "Node"

instance Constructor C1_1UserTree where
  conName _ = "Leaf"
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for this: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection

Comment: @Sibi: Don't think so.

Comment: I think the only way to do something like this is with Template Haskell and haskell-src-meta. I can't imagine the use case for this, however - your explanation doesn't exactly make sense to me.

Comment: @user2407038 I've thought a bit about a "philosophical" ground for use cases for this. Well, generic programming lets one process data structures generically: having only one implementation of an algorithm. What if we want similarly process functions generically (from the set exposed by a module). Say, if a function has 2 arguments, a name, and a result type, and there are generic `encode`&`decode` functions for the types of the arguments and of the result (like that from `ToJSON`&`FromJSON` classes from Aeson), then we could build a program which responds with any plugged-in 2-arg function.

Comment: @user2407038 Yes, it's like a use for Template Haskell. And stuff done by Generic basically can also be done by TH, can't it? Generic gives perhaps a bit more guarantees: if your generic function implementation has type-checked, it is guaranteed to work with any data of the given structure. TH's direct manipulations with syntax can't probably be thought as being guaranteed to work always, on every use (but when the templates are used, the compiler checks them). So the difference is probably in the places (compilation units) where the check is done: where the algorithm is written vs used.